# haskell [char] to bytestring

Tags: haskell

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    let a = ("teeeeeeeeeeeeest","teeeeeeeeeeeest")
    b <- app a
    print b
```

app expects (bytestring,bytestring) not ([char],[char])
how can I convert it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can convert `String`s to `ByteString`s with `Data.ByteString.Char8.pack` (or the lazy `ByteString` version thereof) if your `String` contains only ASCII values or you are interested only in the last eight bits of each `Char`,

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    let a = ("teeeeeeeeeeeeest","teeeeeeeeeeeest")
    b <- app $ (\(x,y) -> (C.pack x, C.pack y)) a
    print b
```

If your `String` contains non-ASCII `Char`s and you are interested in more than only the last eight bits, you will need some other encoding, like `Data.ByteString.UTF8.fromString`.

Answer (score 7):

You could try:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B --to prevent name clash with Prelude
B.pack "Hello, world"
```

A lot of useful functions can be found here:

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/bytestring/Data-ByteString-Char8.html

you could also use `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8`
for lazy bytestrings

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/bytestring/latest/doc/html/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html#v:pack